# PHP/CSS/HTML web nav acting as image in Chrome

Tags: php, html, css

I've been working on a small website but I've got a bit stuck.

In Internet Explorer the website navigation works fine, however in Google Chrome the website is not clickable.

I thought it might have been due to the background image of the navigation so I removed it and that didn't seem to help at all, I ended up removing the style sheet itself and even after that it will wouldn't work.

I have the menu setup as menu.php which is 'included' in all pages.

Below is the menu.php code and the style sheet applied to the menu, the menu is included in each page via `<?php include 'menu.php'?>`

Where am i going wrong?

```css
ul.menu {
list-style-type:none;
width:auto;
position:relative;
display:block;
height:33px;
font-size:.6em;
font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

ul.menu li {
display:block;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

ul.menu li a {
float:left;
color:#A79787;
text-decoration:none;
height:24px;
padding:9px 15px 0;
font-weight:normal;
}

ul.menu li a:hover,.current {
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}

ul.menu .current a {
color:#fff;
font-weight:700;
}

/*NAVY* --Needs updating */
ul.menu.red{
background: #005581;
}

ul.menu.red li a:hover, .menu.red li.current {
background: #005581;
}
```

```html
<?php
if ($_SESSION['acc_t'] == 1)
 { echo'<!DOCTYPE html> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="CSS" href="styles/style3.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="styles/menu_style_old.css" />

     <table width="900px">
      <tr>
       <td>
       <a name="#top">
       <ul class="menu red">
        <li class="current"><a href="index.php" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="myorders.php" target="_self">My Orders</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="mydepartment.php" target="_self">My Department</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="alldepartment.php" target="_self">All Departments</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="admin.php" target="_self">Administration</a></li>
        <li class="current" style="float:right;"><a href="preferences.php" target="_self">My Preferences</a></li>
      </ul>
     </td>
      <td style="float:right; text-align:right;font-size:12px;vertical-align:top;color:#fff;padding:6px;">
       <?php
         echo ("Date/Time: ");
         echo date("h:m:s");
         echo ("- ");
         echo date("Y-m-d ");
      ?><br />
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
';} else { echo'
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="CSS" href="styles/style3.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="styles/menu/menu_style1.css" />  
     <table width="900px">
      <tr>
       <td>
       <a name="#top">
       <ul class="menu red">
        <li class="current"><a href="index.php" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="myorders.php" target="_self">My Orders</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="mydepartment.php" target="_self">My Department</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="alldepartment.php" target="_self">All Departments</a></li>
        <li class="current" style="float:right;"><a href="preferences.php" target="_self">My Preferences</a></li>
      </ul>
     </td>
      <td style="float:right; text-align:right;font-size:12px;vertical-align:top;color:#fff;padding:6px;">
       <?php
         echo ("Date/Time: ");
         echo date("h:m:s");
         echo ("- ");
         echo date("Y-m-d ");
      ?><br />
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div> 
';}
?>
```

Comment: Lesson for next time. code your site first in a standards compliant browser. Which IE is most definately not. Then modify the site to look reasonable in IE

Comment: can you text root path,included page path and menu page path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    </table>
</div>
';} else { echo'
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="CSS" href="styles/style3.css" media="screen">
```

';} else { echo'

has no begin and end php tag

Comment: The beginning?

<?php
if ($_SESSION['acc_t'] == 1)
 { echo'

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Background-Color and margins were acting up.